# Working with Excel files on Android

Tags: android, excel

I am working on a module that should be able to create, read and write to Excel files.
Is there a (recommended?) lightweight Java library for working with excel file that can run on Android?

Suggestions are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found one [jExcelApi by Andy Khan](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=2&ved=0CAsQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjexcelapi.sourceforge.net%2F&rct=j&q=jExcelApi+by+Andrew+khan&ei=SaVvS8GjAZWekQW9qezUBw&usg=AFQjCNE4n-odRPPG4s9IFjj5osB0uSUhZQ)