# Android SMS - in excel format

Tags: android, excel

I would like to save the data extracted from the content provider into the sdcard in excel format. How do i go about it? I have retrieve the data using the cursor.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest thing is to save using CSV to a text file. Excel will allow an easy import of CSV files.

**EDIT:**

A CSV file is just a text file which has the following format...

```
value1,value2,value3
```

In other words each value (or record) is separated by a comma. CSV files aren't the best way to pass certain types of data but as long as none of the values/records have a comma within them they are very simple.

You can create a CSV file which has the first line which designates the column names for Excel such as...

```
FirstName,LastName,PayrollNumber
John,Smith,1234
Bill,Jones,5678
```

When you import into Excel it should give the option to use the first line of the file as the column names and the other lines as the data (values / records). You can also easily write VBA macros for Excel to do this automatically.

Comment: what do you mean by using CSV to text file??

Comment: @user669046: See the EDIT to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can either save a csv file (just a plain text file with comma separated values) or try the library linked in this answer: [Working with Excel files on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191052/working-with-excel-files-on-android/2219859#2219859)

This is a very simplified example that does not even consider if your values have commas in it, but it should give you an idea:

```
public void write() {
  BufferedWriter out;
  try {
    out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outfilename"));
    Cursor cursor = getYourData();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
      out.write(cursor.getString(YOURFIRSTCOLUMN) + "," + cursor.getString(YOURSECONDCOLUMN) + "," + cursor.getString(YOURTHIRDCOLUMN));
      out.newLine();
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // handle any error here
  } finally {
    out.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you go about doing the comma??

Comment: It's very simple. Just add a comma after each value (except the last one in the row)