# Is there any way to open an xls sheet in Android?

Tags: android, excel

I am newbie in Android, so I have limited knowledge.  Can anyone let me to know if there is any way to open an xls sheet in Android?

Comment: Please refer my answer in which i explain about how to create excelsheet in android. i think it is helpful for you. [answer]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919531/how-to-open-excel-sheet-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Without writing your own reader specific to that file format (the spec for which can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd906173%28v=office.12%29.aspx). Be warned, it's like an 1,100 page PDF if you download it), you'll need a library to include in your project, or you could probably attempt to launch it via Intent. I believe most phones have some sort of QuickOffice or similar app installed, but it's certainly no guarantee.

[Here](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) is a Java library for reading/writing Excel files that I found in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191052/working-with-excel-files-on-android).

Answer (score 0):

There are two popular libraries to read and write Excel files with Java (and so, with Android): [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) and [JExcelAPI](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/).

Apache POI is actively maintained (as of 2014), JExcelAPI looks like its not under active development. ApachePOI can read .xlsx files which JExcelAPI cannot, which may be important for a lot of users.

What I like the most about Apache POI is its event-based Parsing model, which has a very low memory profile when reading large Excel sheets. This i especially useful on mobile devices like Android. In my experience, loading a simple Excel file with 2 sheets, a few hundred row and some formulas with JExcelAPI exceeded the memory limit (OutOfMemoryException) of the Dalvik VM on mid to low-end devices (1GB total RAM or less).