# what widget can be used to open excel sheet in Android?

Tags: android, excel

Can anyone please have the pleasure to help to know, what widget can I use to open excel sheet in Android from **"res/raw/Book1.xls"**?
       Any help will really appreciated. THANKs a lot.

Comment: Hi these thread allready exist is not big help but is what i found. enter [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933019/is-there-any-way-to-open-xls-sheet-in-android)

Comment: If you just want to read i think you could use these [link](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaExcel/article.html) is java so it should work to show the file that is a diferent story. Maybe there's a way with google docs. I use webview to show pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a widget within your application, you would probably launch another  application via an [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) (which would require a spreadhseet application such as OpenOffice to be installed).